# Java - Client and Server communication issues

Tags: java, tcp, server, client

I'm trying to create a simple Java Chatting application, but have ran into some problems.

Here is my code below for both Classes:

**Serveur.java :**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Serveur{

    private String msgClient, msgServeur;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private Socket socket;
    private int port;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public Serveur() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Serveur OK...");
        this.port = 21;
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        while(true){
            this.socket = serverSocket.accept();
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
            this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
            this.msgClient = this.in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + this.msgClient);
            this.msgServeur = this.msgClient.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            send(this.msgServeur);
        }
    }

    public void send(String msg) throws IOException{
        this.out.writeBytes(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        Serveur serveur = new Serveur();
    }
}
```

**Client.java :**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client{

    private String sentence;
    private String modifiedSentence;
    private int port;
    private BufferedReader inUser;
    private BufferedReader inServeur;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream out;

    public Client() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        this.sentence = "";
        this.modifiedSentence = "";
        this.port = 21;
        this.inUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        this.socket = new Socket("localhost", this.port);
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        this.inServeur = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = this.inUser.readLine();
        this.out.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        modifiedSentence = this.inServeur.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        this.socket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{
        Client client = new Client();
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems :
- The client sends a message, and the server returns the same message in uppercase. How can I allow the client to send messages without instantly closing it's socket connection?
- The server looks OK, but when I have multiple clients, will anything change having more than one connected client? How could I broadcast messages, and messages to specific clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The client send a message, the server return the same message in
>   uppercase. How can i allow the client to send infinite message and
>   don't destroy itself after sending the first message ?

just have the client use a loop

```
boolean quit = false;
while (!quit) {
    sentence = this.inUser.readLine();
    quit = sentence.trim().equals("quit");
    this.out.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
    modifiedSentence = this.inServeur.readLine();
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
}
this.socket.close();
```

> The server looks ok, but when i will have multiple client, will it
>   make difference between multiple client ? How can i broadcast ? send
>   message to focused client ?

Yes, this server blocks reading the first client so any other client would have to wait. You probably want to put the code for blocking on each client in a separate thread or submit it to an ExecutiveService. And all of the variables that are specific to a client can not be in the single server class since you need one set for each client.

```
while (true) {
    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            boolean quit = false;
            while (!quit) {
                String msgClient = in.readLine();
                quit = msgClient.trim().equals("quit");
                System.out.println("Received: " + msgClient);
                String msgServeur = msgClient.toUpperCase() + '\n';
                out.writeBytes(msgServeur);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all, but when i'm putting the wile true loop in the client, this error appear (eclipse) "this.socket.close();" is unreachable. So have i to delete this line ? When i'm launching the programm, the client can send his first message, but the second message is never send (or never read by the server)... do you know the reason ?

Comment: You should have some sort of test for the client to indicate when they want to quit.

Comment: Yep, if the server say "lol", i deco the client. But he can't send multiple message (the client)

Comment: server needs a corresponding inner loop too.

Comment: Working, thanks for help and sorry for my incomprehension :P

Comment: in.readLine() returns null at end of stream. also why use a boolean for quit? whats wrong with break;

Comment: @WalterM Break would be fine here but generally I want to be able to look at the condition inside the while to atleast know which variables to look for that end the loop. If it is a large while loop a break hidden deep in the middle could make people misunderstand how the code works.  Breaking the loop by  looking for the end of stream could work but we might have to assume the client's user knows how to use a control key to end the stream which can be a problem if you don't know what terminal the client is using or how tech-savvy the user is.